# Is it OK if one asks about dream interpretation over here?

Tags: discussion

I can't find a proper scholar in my locality. Will it be okay if I ask what my dream meant on this site?

Answer (score -1):

In general these questions are asked to guide people to act appropriately according to the teachings of Islam. If you're concerned this dream may lead to your acting in a way which is inappropriate according to Islam, then yes.